# Android DownloadManager not deleting the physical file when remove is called

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am noticing some strange behaviour while using DownloadManager class to download videos from my server.

The videos are downloaded just fine, but when I try to delete them using the `public int remove (long... ids)` function, the physical file doesn't get deleted and memory ultimately isn't released either.

Here's how i am giving the [DownloadManager.Request](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html) object to the DownloadManager's `enqueue` function:

```
Uri target = Uri.fromFile(new File(destinationFolder, Sha1Util.SHA1(url)));
Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setDestinationUri(target);
request.setNotificationVisibility(Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
```

where `destinationFolder` = `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{app's_package_name}/{user_name}`

**NOTE: The remove function is working fine on Lollipop devices but isn't working on prior versions.**